# Any Good approach to Run a piece of code in Background in Java

Tags: java, background-process

I want to run a piece of code in background in java but don't want to use Thread concept. Please refer some better approach.
condition is I don't want this code harm to my running code .

Comment: Spawn a new process ?.. It will not affect your running code as each new process will have its own memory and variables and other things.. Also, why do you think using threads might break your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really absolutely don't want to use Threads, you could spawn a new process using [`Runtime#exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) - Execute a new Java process with the correct class path that executes a program for you. But this is really heavy weight.

If you are OK with creating threads (They have a quite low footprint if used correctly), but don't want to use the `Thread` class directly, you can use an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), for example like this:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
executor.execute(myBackgroundTask);
```

If you have a large problem that you want to parallelize, you can also use the [Fork Join Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html).

It **is** actually a good idea to **not** use the `Thread` class directly - use `Executor` or Fork/Join. But: You will end up using a thread or a new process (under the hood) anyway if you want to run something in the background.

Comment: The basic unit of work that is used with the Executor Framework is not Thread; it is Task.

Comment: @scottb sure. I meant a thread will be used under the hood anyway, so if the OP wants to avoid threads alltogether, that's not an option. I edited my answer to clarify this.